# How do I turn off XHTML validation in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

How do I turn off Sitecore (6.5) XHTML Validation of pages in workflow?

I'm developing and keep running into issues while trying to publish down test pages because they error out. I would prefer to just get the errors as stacktraces in the browser.

I'm not sure if I have changed something before this does this, but I've recently taken on a project to move a Sitecore into a multi-site solution.

I did not have these issues while developing the solution the first time but I was using 6.4 instead of 6.5.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you go into `System -> Settings -> Validation Rules -> Global Rules` if you scroll to the bottom you will see the `Workflow` section.

You can remove the XHTML validation rule from there.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Perfect! I was looking all over the place it seemed and I should have just stepped back and looked closer. I was looking in the sibling folders for options.

Comment: Stephen, have you noticed times where even if you remove this Global Rule, Sitecore still validates XHTML in workflow?

Comment: I had to do this for an HTML5 layout.

Comment: Stephen, since you work for the Mother Ship, any idea when the Sitecore.Layouts.XHtml.cs class will be updated to reflect HTML5 standards?  It's a pity to have to turn off this feature because I have a "nav" element.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to get this to work by going to the following item: `/sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules/Field Types/Rich Text`

From that item, remove the 'Is Xhtml' option from each of the Quick Action Bar, Validate Button, Validator Bar & Workflow fields.

This should disable the XHTML Validation.

Answer (score 1):

In Sitecore 7 and 7.1, you can delete the rule from the following path:

`sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules/Item Rules/Item/Full Page XHtml item`

Answer (score 1):

You can also suppress the validation for the particular Item, Click on Item,you will find Suppressed Validation Rules at the bottom of the Validation section and in the text-box we need to add the Item ID of that validation (Full Page XHtml).

For example `Full Page XHtml, Item ID {9DE34911-96D5-48C3-AFFF-20CFF4D5AB02}`