# Sitecore HTML5 support

Tags: html, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7

I am having issues getting Sitecore 6.6 to support HTML 5 layouts and rich text content. I have followed the instructions [here](http://apaceweb.com/blog/2011/09/05/make-sitecore-rich-text-editor-html-5-ready/), but I still receive validation errors in the admin tools. Has anyone had any luck using HTML 5 with Sitecore? Does anyone know if Sitecore 7 supports HTML 5? Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use HTML5 templates with Sitecore, I am doing so now.  You will want to remove the XHTML validation from your workflow.  To do so navigate to: `System -> Settings -> Validation Rules -> Global Rules`
Scroll down to workflow and simply remove the **Full Page XHtml** rule as shown here:

[image]

You might go to the next level and create your own HTML5 validation rule... or (fingers crossed) Sitecore will be creating one soon.

You can also reference [Stephen Pope's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8452198/988355) - that's where I learned this handy trick.

Comment: Hi Patrick. Thank you for your response. When I go to System - Settings - Validation Rules - Global Rules and then scroll down to the Workflow section, I only see one folder on the left panel: Item Rules. It contains Broken Links, Duplicate Name, and Media Size Too Big. There is nothing in the Selected panel. Are you using Sitecore 6?

Comment: Yes, in fact that screenshot is from Sitecore 6.4.1.

Comment: I wanted to update this with what I ended up doing in case anyone else runs across it. I ended up leaving the default validation in place and reworking my admin tools so users didn't have to enter HTML5 elements in the richtext editors. I was still able to use HTML5 layouts and sublayouts with no issue and no longer see the validation errors.