# sitecore RTE removes empty attributes

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

Using the RTE in Sitecore 7.2 (probably other versions as well), if an empty attribute is added to an element in HTML view, switching to Design view and then back to HTML view, the empty attribute is removed. For example, I added `<span data-test="">test</span>` then clicked Design and then HTML, and my element turned into `<span>test</span>`.

I know the Telerik RadEditor is an XHTML editor, but on the [Telerik Demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/builtincontentfilters/defaultcs.aspx) page, the `ConvertToXhtml` can be disabled and the editor behaves as I would like it to behave.  How can the `ConvertToXhtml` be disabled using Sitecore?

I've tried removing

```
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.FixXHtml.ConvertToXHtml, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
```

from the `fixXHtml` pipeline, but that didn't change the behavior.  I also tried following [How do I turn off XHTML validation in Sitecore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452005/how-do-i-turn-off-xhtml-validation-in-sitecore) but that only changed validation after the fact (the empty attribute was removed before showing Sitecore validation warnings/errors).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this article will help:

[Prevent Sitecore Content Editor From Stripping Script Tags](http://firebreaksice.com/prevent-sitecore-content-editor-from-stripping-script-tags/)

Hopefully, you should just need to substitute "RemoveScripts" with "ConvertToXhtml"

Comment: Thanks, as noted on the page, there is now a setting in the web.config for `RemoveScripts`, but the original solution works for `ConvertToXhtml`.